# Is there any way in javascript to call multiple functions by name and get their result in array format?

Tags: javascript, lodash

For example if i have

```
 fun1(){}
 fun2() {}
 fun3() {}
```

these function not having any http calls or not any db operations in them

call the function [fun1,fun2,fun3] and get their result in some array format 
by using some module like lodash or some thing else

Comment: Why not just `[fun1(), fun2(), fun3()]`?

Comment: I guess OP thinks this is "dirty", so wants something like `magic([func1, func2, ...])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with three functions that each return a value. You can store the functions in an array and `map` to a `results` array:

```js
const a = () => 1;
const b = () => 2;
const c = () => "a";
    
const funcs = [a, b, c];
const results = funcs.map(e => e());    

console.log(results);
```

Comment: `Promise.all` is a good example of this very thing, where all of the functions are asynchronous.